# extract estimate of a gls

Tags: r, nlme, ape-phylo

I'm trying to extract a parameter from a model fit by ML which has a correlation structure obtained from corPagel (defined in package ape). The parameter of interest is within the element named **apVar** in the summary.

```
library(ape); library(nlme)
cor_lambdaML <- corPagel( 1, avestree, fixed=FALSE )
m <- gls(AUTUMN ~ GREGARIOUSNESS + SEASON + TARSUS + MATURATION + SPRING + MIGRATION + DICHROMATISM + HABITAT + POSTJUVENILE + CONSPICUOUSNESS, correlation = cor_lambdaML, data = avesdata, method = 'ML' )
names(m)
m$apVar
```

This code produces the following output (please, download a dput with model m [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/28VWV5gB/m_online.html)):

```
           corStruct     lSigma
corStruct 0.03848807 0.03090663
lSigma    0.03090663 0.04403168
attr(,"Pars")
  corStruct      lSigma 
0.858126838 0.008131981 
attr(,"natural")
[1] TRUE
```

Extracting values of the first matrix is trivial, but how can I extract the value of corStruct within the element **attr(, "Pars")**?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how far you need to dig, but `m$Pars$corStruct` is where the data are stored.  Which is to say:  `m` is a `list` with many components, one of which is `Pars` . That itself is a `list`, with a component `corStruct` .

`?glsObject` will start you on the path to details of all the list elements.

Comment: As far as I understand, Pars is not a list component of my gls object. The component apVar contains one covariate matrix and two elements which I can't extract. If a try 'm$Pars$corStruct' returns a NULL; if I try 'm$apVar$Pars' returns the error $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors; 'm1023$apVar[[3,1]]' returns subindex out of limits. Any clue?

Comment: No idea. You could use `names` to find all the elements of `m` and recursively find the elements of those list elements.

Comment: Apparently, there's no way to reach these elements. The structure of m$apVar states there is an element `..- attr(*, "Pars")= Named num [1:2] 0.85813 0.00813`, but if I try `m$apVar..- attr(*, "Pars")` it doesn't like the asterisk. Then, if I try `m$apVar..- attr(3, "Pars")` I get numeric(0)

Comment: `m$apVar$Pars` doesn't get it?

Comment: Nop! As I said it elicits an error message: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Then you'll probably have to dig into the code for the appropriate `print` method for objects of class `glsObject` .  Bummer

Answer (score -1):

just `attr(m, "Pars")`